# Peut-on utiliser le conditionnel après «si» comme dans «si tu aurais du»

Tags: conditionnel, concordance-des-temps

Ma question est simple mais il faut comprendre le contexte. Par chance, le contexte contient deux jeux de mots *vraiment drôles*.

Imaginons que Alice ce soit fait une entorse et aille chez le médecin. Le médecin lui dit que, habituellement, elle devrait passer une radio mais vu la situation actuelle (épidémie de Covid-19, hôpitaux saturés) ça n'est pas souhaitable. Alice va juste porter une attelle en espérant que ça ne soit pas trop grave.

Alice écrit ensuite à son frère Bob pour lui relater son aventure:

> Aujourd'hui, lors d'une ballade, je suis tombée. Je porte une attelle.

Puisque Bob est bon en orthographe, il a remarqué le L en trop dans «balade». Puisqu'il ne manque jamais une occasion de faire un trait d'humour, celui-ci répond:

> J'espère que tu n'as pas trop mal. Mais qu'est-ce que tu étais en train de chanter?

Réponse de Alice:

> Je n'ai pas trop mal, mais normalement j'aurais du passer une radio, ça n'est donc pas si bénin. Et pour info, je ne chantais pas!

Bob étant décidément un gai luron, il voit l'occasion de faire un deuxième trait d'humour, au risque de faire une grosse faute de concordance des temps:

> Si tu aurais du passer à la radio, c'est que tu étais bien en train de chanter!

Ma question est la suivante: est-ce que la dernière phrase de Bob est correcte?

Comment: « … je *me suis* trébuchée. »  j’***ai*** trébuché — … une grosse faut***e*** — Si tu devais passer …

Comment: @Personne, « si tu devais passer... » n'a pas de notion de «Alice *aurait dû être obligée de* passer si les circonstances avaient été normales mais elle *ne peut pas* passer.

Comment: En cliquant sur le deuxième onglet "edit" en dessous des *tags* de votre question, vous pouvez corriger votre texte — En mettant le pointeur sur "edit" de votre commentaire, vous pouvez ensuite le supprimer, ce que je ferais tout à l’heure pour le mien.

Comment: Accessoirement il y avait fort peu de chances que Alice comprenne la blague de Bob qui est quand même très subtile...

Answer (score 2):

Non, elle n'est pas correcte: dans une subordonnée conditionnelle avec *si*, on ne met jamais le conditionnel (règle souvent résumée par "les *si* n'aiment pas les *rai*).

La phrase correcte est *si tu as dû passer à la radio, c'est que tu étais bien en train de chanter*
OU: *si tu devais passer à la radio, c'est que tu étais bien en train de chanter*

C'est une faute néanmoins courante dans le français parlé, mais elle est toujours stigmatisée comme une "grosse" faute.

Comment: @Mathieu — « si tu as ***dû***  passer à la radio » est une tournure à ne pas employer. en langage commun on dit qu’elle est "lourdingue", elle peut être prononcée par des enfants, mais cette façon de parler signe un manque de maîtrise du français de la part du locuteur.

Comment: @Greg, merci pour la réponse mais dans «si tu as du passer» il y a l'implication que Alice est réellement passée (ce qui n'est pas le cas). La deuxième proposition «si tu devais passer» implique que Alice devait y aller, mais n'a pas été (ce qui n'est pas non plus le cas, je médecin lui a dit de ne pas y aller). Comment exprimer le fait que, dans des circonstances normales, elle aurait du y aller, mais qu'en fait elle ne doit pas?

Comment: @Personne, quelle aurait été une bonne alternative à la phrase de Bob alors? Je ne vois pas bien en quoi «si tu as dû» est «lourdingue».

Comment: @Mathieu — C’est le *si* (affirmation ou opposition) et le temps du verbe devoir qui me gêne ici, le remplacer par *bien que* ou *quoique* (qui marquent une concession) est plus audible et va dans le sens de vos commentaires